# Python Pool Multiprocessing Requests Hanging

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

The code in my program essentially conducts 10 python requests simultaneously and processes their output also simultaneously, it was working for a while but I changed something and can't work out what broke it.

The following code is the code that calls, the code appears to freeze between lines 3 and 4, so in the process of doing the multithreaded requests.

The line 'print("failed to close") does not print, appearing to indicate that the program does not reach the pool.close() instruction.

```
listoftensites = listoftensites
pool = Pool(processes=10) # Initalize a pool of 10 processes
listoftextis, listofonline = zip(*pool.map(onionrequestthreaded, listoftensites)) # Use the pool to run the function on the items in the iterable
print("failed to close ")
pool.close()
 # this means that no more tasks will be added to the pool
pool.join()
```

The function which is called at which it hangs, is immediately after the line 'print("failed in return")', this would appear to indicate that the requests do not terminate properly and return the expected values.

```
def onionrequestthreaded(onionurl):
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {}
    session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
    session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'

    onionurlforrequest = "http://" + onionurl
    #print(onionurlforrequest)
    print("failed with proxy session")
    try:
        print("failed in request")
        r = session.get(onionurlforrequest, timeout=15, allow_redirects=True)
        online = 2
        print("failed in text extraction")

        textis = r.text
    except:
        print("failed in except")

        #print("failed")
        online = 1

        textis = ""
    print("failed in return")
    return textis, online
```

Very confusing but i'm probably doing something simple. Please let me know if there's a solution to this as i'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: Did you try r.close() or "with session.get() as r:"?